# Is there a need in Magento 2.4 for Cache warmer extension or Google Page Speed Optimizer?

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, speedoptimization

```
Magento ver. 2.4.2
4 x 2.50 GHz Cores
8 GB RAM
5 TB Bandwidth
5000 Mbps Network Out
```

We used to run Magento 1.9.4 but are switching to Magento 2.4.2. Every time I installed Magento 2.x it always seemed very slow on the back-end (we haven't set up the front end yet to see) even though I have done all the recommended optimisations.

Now I found 2 extensions created by Amasty:

- Full Page Cache Warmer
- Google Page Speed Optimizer

They are not the cheapest ones so I was wondering **if this would help with Magento 2 or is Magento 2.x designed in such a way where this is no longer needed?** Historically (on our Magento 1.9.4) we had a hard time with Caching extensions so we ended up disabling it (I guess we weren't able to configure them properly).

Comment: For Magento backend Performance Tuning, Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Is slow performance still an issue for your server?  If so, please provide data requested for workload analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.  Have a GREAT 2024.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you state that the Magento backend is slow. The modules you mentioned are for frontend optimisation and will have absolutely no effect on the backend performance. On a properly spec'd and configured host server Magento administration (backend) should be fast.

Is your host in a virtual/shared environment or dedicated? I would suggest that your host is a little under spec'd for a production Magento2 site.

I recommend using Varnish for Magento 2 full page frontend caching. After you have got your site built, tested and ready for production you can then look more closely at optimising your frontend Lighthouse rating (PageSpeed) and whether your full page cache  requires to be "warmed".

Answer (score 0):

I won't tell you for backend optimization (Redis is much recommanded - but still my own backend is quite slow compared to my old Magento 1.9), but I know the Amasty modules very well.

I won't recommand their Google Page Speed Optimizer, I had many troubles with it.

Instead, I strongly recommand this one: https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/page-speed/

It is working out of the box and it is the best module I have tested so far (support is very good too).

Regarding Full Page Cache Warmer, I'm currently using it. Except that the cache warmer functionnality to warm logged customers is faulty, I'm having the support to debug again and again.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Those two extensions you mentioned don't help with slow backends. Problem might be in something else.

Cache != Performance.

Although cache warmers might be useful, I'd suggest you try and identify what it is that's slowing the Magento down, out of box Magento 2 with Luma theme isn't that slow after all.

You could try:

- Profile code with tools like new relic, tideways or similar
- Perform a 3rd-party extension audit, turn them all off and see if speed is better. If it is, turn them back on one by one and find the module that breaks performance.
- Switch to a default Luma theme and see if it makes a difference. If it does - it's your theme that's slowing down the site and you might want to investigate it further.